# wifi trouble shooting

Tags: password, sudo

I'm quite new to Linux. I am currently using Ubuntu on my HP Celeron laptop. I've been having trouble with my wifi on my laptop. I've tried pressing the button to activate my wifi but it doesn't seem to be responding. So, I'm trying to run this troubleshooting command:

sudo lshw -C network

But when i try AND PRESS enter, it asks for a sudo password. First of all, What is it? Secondly, Where do I get it? I'd really appreciate some help. I need to get back on the network at work asap.

Thanks.

Comment: For your answer : [Click Here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/512793/upgraded-12-04-lts-to-14-04-lts-now-wireless-networking-is-disabled)

Answer (score 0):

Sudo is short for `super user do` and it is the application that lets you do root tasks without switching users. Your sudo password is going to be the same password you use to login. For more information, type `man sudo` at the cmd line.

As for the rest, I'm just going to copy (with very slight modification) from [Novice's answer to another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/512824/22949):

Try this command:

```
sudo ip link set wlan0 up
```

If it doesn't work then try this:

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

If that also doesn't work then may be drivers for Wireless is not installed, you need to install it manually.

Comment: I've tried that and it gets me to a prompt to type in a password. but when i do it doesn't respond. nothing types. i don't know why.

Comment: It isn't meant to show on screen because it is a password. You wouldn't want someone to come along later and see your password. Just press enter when you've finished.